# Why is my Notepad ++ just displaying in symbols?

Tags: notepad++, symbols, undefined-symbol

My Notepad++ was working fine a day ago, but I opened a file up all of a sudden to edit in Notepad++ and I'll I'm seeing now are all these symbols. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the program, but that didn't work. Any ideas how to fix this?

[image: Current Notepad++]

Comment: Use `Ctrl+N` to change the encoding ?

Comment: What is the file extension of the file opened? ex. filename.ext <=

Comment: @zer00ne it's a .twbx (Tableau workbook), but I'm seeing the same issue when I even try opening up a word doc in Notepad++

Comment: @Luke.SWK changing the encoding doesn't help me unfortunately =/

Comment: Note the PK in the beginnig. Looks like a zip file. change extension to zip. Then try to open it with your favorit archiver.

Comment: @stickybit not a zip file unfortunately. seeing it with all file types as well, even just simple word docs.

Comment: Notepad++ can't open .doc unless there's a plugin that I'm not aware of, nor can it open a zip file. The only way it's possible is if the .doc is converted to html...but docs are a horrible mess when converted to html. Notepad++ opens text files , doc files are much more complex than a text file.

Comment: I also suspect your opening binary files. At least a `doc` definitely is one (and at least a `docx` is a ziped XML, so that could explain seeing the `PK` there to). What happens if you open one of the files you have the problem with with Notepad (the regular one, without `++`)?

Comment: @stickybit For some reason, I'm getting the same issue when I try opening a doc file in normal notepad =/

Comment: Then there is no issue here. That's what you get, when opening a non-text file in a text file editor. Use the proper program for opening files, e.g. Word for .doc.